# Apart from common enemies and survival, what are the factors that make players collaborative?

Tags: survival

Apart from common enemies and survival, what are the other factors that make players collaborative in an open world game?

For example:
In Rust(https://rust.facepunch.com), randomly spawned players tend to kill one another and loot items. 
In The Forest(https://endnightgames.com), players tend to collaborate to survive against mutants.

I read through this question, [Designing fictional non-competitive games](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48759/designing-fictional-non-competitive-games/), but only sports are mentioned mostly. Environment vs Players is also a factor mentioned in there.

Comment: This might be a better question for the GameDev.SE: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: What @Pleiades said or maybe the [RPG site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't see those SE's.

Comment: Would you like to see if we can get this question migrated over to one of those sites?

Comment: You can do that? Migrating questions to other SE's? @AndyD273

Comment: I can't, but I can flag it for a Mod to move. They should be able to. If you want anyway. Or you can leave it here and try over there too. It'll probably get closed on WB since it's not really about world building, but you might still get a couple answers.

Comment: Ah I see, @AndyD273 Thanks! Maybe leave it here for a while til this gets closed by Mods and I will try over there too.

Comment: @SawThinkarNayHtoo No problem, but minor clarification; the mods won't close it. It is something that the users will do. Anyone that gets enough rep gains certain privileges, and at a certain level you get access to some mod tools, like being able to vote to close or reopen a question. You can check out the [help] and [tour], and also visit the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor).

Comment: Since it's a game, people do what positive and negative feedback guide them to do. If you want collaboration, provide positive feedback (like points or extra resources) for collaboration and provide negative feedback (like penalties or reduced resources) for loners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do people do the things they do?  It always breaks down to 3 things:   **money, sex and family**.

Your 2 examples in the OP are money.  People get immediate loot return by looting a dead player.  Or they can improve their return by cooperating with a player to kill and loot NPCs.

Sex is probably not applicable in these sorts of games, but the internet is full of surprises.

"Family" is a motivator and this includes family, tribe, sect, team and so on.  If players have colors to show what faction they are allied with, a player from the same faction might hesitate to kill a brother.  Others in his faction might find out.  Conversely, a brother might be counted on to cooperate or watch your back at the least, picking off some random bastard who has you in his sights.

Comment: I don't know that I would say _everyone_ is motivated by money, sex, and family. I know plenty of people who will do pretty much anything for a snack or a place to crash for the night. Extrinsic motivators are pretty much endless, but all our basic intrinsic needs relate directly back to our own survival and the survival of our family. Probably being a bit pedantic, but ehhhh

Comment: @Pleiades Right. There are also some who would do anything just out of curiosity without expecting any incentive.

Comment: I think @willk is underestimating sex in the OPs examples... money is virility, griefing is virility, teabagging your fallen foes is virility... probably pointless virility, but it all stems from sex.  Sex and family are the same thing... and all of them are survival.  I suspect we are WAY simpler than we like to convince ourselves.

Comment: @Saw Thinkar Nay Htoo "If you look in this box I will remove your genetalia"  I think curiosity is a huge motivater, but only when we are bored because our other needs are met (or alternately, can't be met).  I expect the number of people who would trade sex/family for the option to be curious is statistically insignificant.

Comment: @OhkaBaka `but it all stems from sex` Ok there Sigmund, calm down :)

Comment: @OhkaBaka people in real life would probably not open that box. People in a game probably would.

Comment: Absolutely... but as a narrative motivation, "because it exists" isn't exactly compelling.

Answer (score 5):

Put a series of obstacles that can't be resolved just by one person but need different abilities from different people. For example, in Golden Sun (GBA game) or Stranger Things Game (for mobile) each character has specific abilities for specific obstacles you need to solve to enter certain areas or kill certain enemies. If you couldn't control all characters (in the games mentioned, you can), you'd have to team up with people that can do what you can't.

Information could also be useful for collaboration. Maybe only each class, or the citizens of each city have crucial pieces of information relevant to the plot and the only way advance is to collaborate with each other to get the complete puzzle/history.

Comment: This is interesting. A dungeon that requires you to have at lease one mage and one rogue to get all the way to the bottom, and keep eachother alive throughout otherwise you won't be able to progress further (for instance)

Answer (score 1):

You may add a **fame system** in your game.

When a player do collaborative actions, he earns fame points that he can use to upgrade and gain new skills or items. He may need a certain amount of fame to become a team leader, or create a guild, etc.

A player can also reward with a few fame points another player who helped him.

On the opposite, a player killer would loose fame points for each kill, and then would have a restricted acces to cities or NPCs, etc.